# Asymptotics of A261668

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, asymptotics, zeta-functions

In  [Uniform Approach to Double Shuffle and Duality Relations of Various q-Analogs of Multiple Zeta Values via Rota-Baxter Algebras](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.8044), Proposition 10.8, Jianqiang Zhao mentiones the sequence:
$$a_n=\sum_{1\leq d,k\leq n}\sum_{\substack{x_1+\dots+x_d=d+k-1\\1\leq x_1,\dots,x_d}}x_1 x_2\cdots x_d. $$
(Actually under the first sum it reads $1\leq d\leq k\leq n$, but this is probably a typo, since in Table 8 on the same page, the sequence starts with $1,8,49,\dots$, which is what you get when you sum over  ${1\leq d,k\leq n}$; see also the oeis-entry: https://oeis.org/A261668.)

Numerically, from the first few values it seems like the asymptotic of this sequence might be the following.

**Edit**: in a previous version, as  Richard Stanley pointed out, I gave the asymptotic expansion for $a_{n+1}$. See his comments for a simple formula and generating function for $a_n$. Here the corrected guess for the asymptotics for $a_n$.

$$a_n=  \frac{\sqrt{3} \left(\frac{27}{4}\right)^{n}}{6 \, \sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{n}}  \left(\frac{3}{10} -\frac{223}{6000 \, n} + \frac{26689}{21600000 \, n^{2}} + \frac{31824349}{23328000000 \, n^{3}} + \frac{28917508109}{167961600000000 \, n^{4}} - \frac{84601010659543}{302330880000000000 \, n^{5}} - \frac{473846767572852311}{3265173504000000000000 \, n^{6}} + \frac{479343612166541515679}{5877312307200000000000000 \, n^{7}} + \frac{1396880611451268708008387}{16926659444736000000000000000 \, n^{8}} - \frac{4768678908408186461643400733}{274211883004723200000000000000000 \, n^{9}} \pm O\left(\frac{1}{n^{10}}\right)\right)$$

Has it been proved somewhere, that this is the correct asymptotic?

Comment: I edited formula following the link OEIS, please check

Comment: Maybe, it is better to remove $k$ in RHS and replace condition to $x_1+\dots+x_d\leq n+d-1$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Maybe, but I want to stay somewhat close to the notation in Zhao's paper.

Comment: It is routine to show that $a_n=\sum_{d=1}^n{2d+n-1\choose n-1}$. Moreover, $a_n+1$ is the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in $1/(1-x)^{n+1}(1+x)$. It shouldn't be difficult to get the asymptotics from this.

Comment: @RichardStanley Thanks, that's definitely helpful!

Comment: The tail end of Richard's sum is close to geometric with ratio 9/4, so the asymptotic value is 9/5 times the last term.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I'm not sure I understand correctly what you mean. Do you suggest a simple way to get the leading coefficient $C$ of the asymtotic, such that $a_n\sim C^n$? As stated I expect that $C=\frac{27}{4}$ and not $\frac{9}{4}$ (or $\frac{9}{5}$).

Comment: The largest term in $\sum_{d=1}^n {2d+n-1\choose n-1}$ is ${3n-1\choose n-1}$. It is asymptotic to $\frac 16\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(\frac{27}{4}\right)^n$. If we multiply the constant $1/6$ by $9/5$ we get $3/10$, not $81/40$. Numerically, $3/10$ seems to be the correct constant, confirming Brendan's comment.

Comment: Note that $\frac{81}{40}=\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{27}{4}$. Perhaps the stated asymptotic expansion is for $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: @RichardStanley You are right, I accidently stated the asymptotic expansion for $a_{n+1}$. I will edit the post.

Comment: Notice that it also equals http://oeis.org/A225006 minus 1, which contains an empirical asymptotics based on recurrent relation (which now can be proved) and provides yet another interpretation for these quantities.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev How nice! Thanks for editing the oeis-entry! Maybe we should the formula with the sum of binomial coefficients as well.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: Done.